# SCNCylinder diffuse.contents - Render different contents for both radius and height sections

Tags: scenekit

Is there any way to render different contents for both radius and height sections

I am trying to use a cylinder shaped object and rendering image on it using diffuse.contents of SCMaterial instance

```
myCustomMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "image")
```

It renders this image on cylinder, however same image gets rendered on both height and render section.

I would like to render a different image on height section than radius section. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an array of materials.

```
let cylinder = SCNCylinder(radius: 1.0, height: 1.0)
let cylinderNode = SCNNode(geometry: cylinder)
let fillMurray = SCNMaterial()
fillMurray.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "fillmurray460x300")
let kitten = SCNMaterial()
kitten.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "kitten140")
cylinder.materials = [fillMurray, kitten]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, it flipped (mirrored) the second image.

Comment: Nevermind. I was able to transform it using contentsTransform. Thanks alot

Comment: Interesting. I wonder what it did to the other end of the cylinder! For another approach to flipping, you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638532/setting-contents-images-on-scncylinder-is-reversed-flipped.

Comment: I had to use contentsTransform on both ends i.e for both images material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1,-1,1). But I will try to use the solution you mentioned in different answer.