# Setting contents (images) on SCNCylinder is reversed (flipped)

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have trying to render an image on SCNCylinder object using following code:

```
    let coinGeometry = SCNCylinder(radius: 50, height: 55)
    coinNode = SCNNode(geometry: coinGeometry)
    coinNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 25.0, 25.0)
    coinScene.rootNode.addChildNode(coinNode)

   //Add image on cylinder shape
    let frontFacingImageMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    frontFacingImageMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "map")
    frontFacingImageMaterial.specular.contents = UIColor.blueColor()
    frontFacingImageMaterial.shininess = 5.0
    coinGeometry.firstMaterial = frontFacingImageMaterial
```

On cylinder, this image is being shown as reversed (flipped). How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't flip the original image data, just flip the way it gets mapped onto the geometry. Set `frontFacingImageMaterial.diffuse.contentsTransform` to a matrix that flips either X or Y.

Answer (score 3):

From [How to flip UIImage horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404706/how-to-flip-uiimage-horizontally):

```
UIImage* sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"];
UIImage* flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage 
                                        scale:sourceImage.scale
                           orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
```

So in Swift, something like:

```
if let originalImage = UIImage(named: "map") {
    let materialImage = UIImage(CGImage: originalImage.CGImage!, 
                                scale: originalImage.scale, 
                                orientation: .UpMirrored)
}
```